# String.Replace in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website and I want to search entities using LINQ. Currently I have a working search function. However, I want to add a feature which replaces characters in strings before running the search. This is due to the fact that in Farsi, there are two similar representations of a single character and I want to run the search for both of them.

The working code is this (a very simplified version):

```
var model = db.Restaurants.Where(r => r.Name.ToUpper().Contains(query));
```

what I want to do is this:

```
query = query.Replace('آ', 'ا'); //couple of other fixes too...
var model = db.Restaurants.Where(r => r.Name.ToUpper().Replace('آ', 'ا').Contains(query));
```

Obviously, this gives me the error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Replace(Char, Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Currently the only thing that comes to my mind is to store the replaced strings into database and query those strings. This is not a clean approach in my opinion. Another option is to run the query in code (query `Restaurant`s one by one) which isn't efficient at all. Caching those values is going to help but again, I think there's a better way. That's why I asked this question to see if there is some way to transfer this query to database.

Comment: Its true that you are showing *a very simplified version*, because you call `FixFarsiChars` method in your real code

Comment: try `var model = db.Restaurants.AsEnumerable().where(....`

Comment: Which version of EF do you use? In v6 you could solve this by a command interceptor.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes and no. Sorry for no consistency between the error and the code. I'll fix that. But there are at least 12 criteria running on the entity and I didn't want to bore you with that.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, I'm using version 6. Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Instead to use string functions you should use SqlFunctions. [Quoting SqlFunctions Class docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) Not all functions are supported-

Comment: @danihp I tried using `SqlFunctions` but didn't find anything for `String.Replace`. Is there any?

Comment: I also miss this function. If your dataset is small try to convert it to enumerate as @Damith suggest to you.

Comment: @Damith isn't that the 2nd approach (as a solution) I mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Entity Framework 6 you can use command interceptors. It sounds complicated, but they've made it easy as pie.

First create a class that implements `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbCommandInterceptor`. Only one implemented method matters, the others can just be stubs:

```
public class MyCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command,
                DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("a", "b");
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, 
                DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    { }

    ... lots of stubs
}
```

And you activate the interceptor by calling

```
DbInterception.Add(new MyCommandInterceptor());
```

somewhere in the initialization of you application.

Comment: I definitely have to look more into this but just a quick question. I see that you've used `command.CommandText.Replace("a", "b");`. If I use this in all of my queries, wouldn't that prevent me from inserting `"a"` into database or getting a `string` containing `"a"`?

Comment: It's just an example. In reality you should probably check for something like ` IN ` in your query. Further, I think you can safely replace Farsi characters because they won't occur in reserved words :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll start playing around with it. It seems like the best option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the suggested approach and fixed the problem. Gonna blog it soon :D

Comment: Great! Maybe you can post a link to your blog when it's there.